# How do I make a class inherit from lxml.objectify.Element?

Tags: python, inheritance, lxml, lxml.objectify

I have a Python class for a `Person` object which inherits [`xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element).

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
class Person(ElementTree.Element):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__("person", name=name, age=str(age))

person = Person("Paul", 23)
```

I plan on expanding my `Person` class to include additional attributes and subtags. Before doing this, I want to simplify attribute access by converting my class to use [`lxml.objectify.Element`](http://lxml.de/objectify.html).

```
from lxml import objectify
class Person(objectify.Element):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__("person", name=name, age=str(age))

person = Person("Paul", 23)
```

Unfortunately, trying to inherit from `objectify.Element` raises a TypeError about creating `cython_function_or_method` instances.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/svascellar/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 2, in <module>
    class Person(objectify.Element):
TypeError: cannot create 'cython_function_or_method' instances
```

**Why is my class raising a TypeError? How do I inherit frrom `lxml.objectify.Element`?**

Comment: You don't because `lxml.objectify.Element` is not a type.

Comment: As the error says: `objectify.Element` is not a class, it's a `cyfunction` (a function coded in Cython http://cython.org/), so you cannot inherit from it.

Comment: Related: [Difficulty creating lxml Element subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19096413/3357935)

Answer (score 2):

#### In hindsight, I recommend *against* using `lxml` to create subclasses.

As the comments mentioned, [`lxml.objectify.Element()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.objectify-module.html#Element) is not a class. It is a [factory method](https://pythonspot.com/factory-method/) that creates and returns an object, meaning it cannot be inherited.

While it's possible to inherit from [`ElementBase`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.ElementBase-class.html) or [`ObjectifiedElement`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement-class.html), the lxml documentation strongly warns that you must not override `__init__` or `__new__`, which my original answer did.

> **BIG FAT WARNING**: Subclasses must not override `__init__` or `__new__` as it is absolutely undefined when these objects will be created or destroyed. All persistent state of Elements must be stored in the underlying XML. If you really need to initialize the object after creation, you can implement an _init(self) method that will be called directly after object creation.
>   <sub>- [Documentation for `lxml.etree.ElementBase`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.ElementBase-class.html)</sub>

I suggest inheriting from a different class instead. As mentioned in the original question, you can inherit from [`lxml.etree.ElementTree.Element`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) fairly easily.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
class Person(ElementTree.Element):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__("person", name=name, age=str(age))

person = Person("Paul", 23)
```

Working with sub-classes of `lxml` may be more trouble than it's worth. However, if you *really* want to subclass `lxml` despite the warnings, you can see my original answer below.

---

## Old Answer (Unsafe)

Try inheriting from `lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement` instead.

```
from lxml import objectify
class person(objectify.ObjectifiedElement):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__(name=name, age=str(age))

my_person = person("Paul", 23)
print(etree.tostring(my_person, encoding="unicode"))
# output: <person age="23" name="Paul"/>
```

Make sure that your class name matches your XML tag, as `ObjectifiedElement` uses the class name for the root XML tag name.

As [Goyo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366392/how-do-i-make-a-class-inherit-from-lxml-objectify-element#comment85733629_49366392) and [bruno desthuilliers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366392/how-do-i-make-a-class-inherit-from-lxml-objectify-element#comment85733742_49366392) pointed out, `objectify.Element` is not a class, which means you can't inherit from it. Going off their comments, I used `type()` to confirm this for myself and discovered that `objectify.Element()` returned an object of type `ObjectifiedElement`.

```
from lxml import objectify
person = objectify.Element("person", name="Paul", age="23")
print(type(person))
# output: <class 'lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement'>
```

After changing my class to inherit from `lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement`, the class worked as expected.

Comment: Below where you quote the big fat warning in the lxml documentation, you've written "As mentioned in the original question, you can inherit from `lxml.etree.ElementTree.Element` fairly easily." - should that be `xml.` not `lxml.`?